# Find what accesses an address

Tags: c++, memory, exception

**What it's supposed to do:** Let's say someone wants to edit a variable in your program. Well, you will be able to see the address that tampers with that variable (like maybe a `mov` instruction).

**How I thought of doing it:** I get the address of that variable, I use `VirtualProtect` to put a `PAGE_GUARD` protection on it and create a vectored exception handler that checks for `EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE` and checks if the address accessed is the one protected and if so it saves the address that last accessed that one (from the context).

Now, I started simply by just trying to make a simple handler to see if it can notify me when a change is being made, but it does not work. Firstly, whenever I try to `printf` the address of the variable which has the `PAGE_GUARD` on it I get an access exception or it just crashes if I launch it outside of Visual Studio.

I also tried setting a `PAGE_NOACCESS` and handling the `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in the vectored handler, but then nothing happens.

```
long __stdcall handler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExceptInfo) {
    if (EXCEPTION_GUARD_PAGE == pExceptInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode)
        printf("accessed by 0x%p\m", pExceptInfo->ContextRecord->Esp);

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

int main() {
    int32_t nNumber         = 555111222;
    UINT_PTR uiNumberAddr   = ReCa<UINT_PTR>(&nNumber);

    DWORD dwOld(0);
    VirtualProtect(reintepret_cast<void*>(uiNumberAddr), sizeof(uiNumberAddr), PAGE_GUARD, &dwOld);
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, handler);

    for (;;) {};

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts on my idea and why it does not work?

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: Given the code provided, I think it doesn't work because there are bugs in the code.

Comment: For reverse engineering purposes. In addition, I think it's pretty interesting @Eljay Yeah, probably. Don't see any though

Comment: OOPS forgot to paste the code. Edited it in

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `printf` from within the handler.  And Guard Pages are not the right way to go about it, since any access to the entire page (and not just the variable you're interested in) will trigger the one-shot guard (which will need to be reset to detect the next access).

Comment: Why shouldn't I do that from within the handler and how would I go about printing the address? And how would I go on only protecting the address?